# Breaking down walls with Iaijutsu Focus

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, damage

So, a character needs to cut through a stone surface. He has Iaijutsu Focus, and he can take his time to do so.

While calculating the amount of time needed to cut the required amount of stone I've noticed that Iaijutsu Focus mentions how against objects the damage is halved, like in case of normal weapon damage. Which would be fine... Except I didn't find anything about halving normal weapon damage in SRD? There is Hardness, which already subtracts some damage, but I didn't see anything about halving... At least, in 3.5. I didn't play 3.0 to know that for sure, but it does look like a rule that was thrown out during the transition to 3.5.

So, the question is - how DOES it work? Do I just subtract Hardness from overall damage? Do I subtract Hardness from overall damage yet divide only Iaijutsu damage by 2? Or do I ignore the dividing part of the rule and just subtract the Hardness from overall damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is an un-errata-d bit of text.

In the original print of Oriental Adventures, the line you mentioned was on page 59.  That line was in error: there is no reason that your damage would be halved against inanimate objects, and your Iaijutsu damage isn't halved either

In the errata for OA, it says:

> p. 58–59: Strike the sentence that crosses the page,
>   "Your extra damage is halved, just like your ordinary
>   damage."

So this was basically a bit of incorrect text, and can safely be ignored.  You do full damage to inanimate objects with Iaijutsu Focus.